# What is a good starter macro book?

Tags: macro, books

Are there are good starter books for macro photography?  There's a few really popular books in other areas of photography that seem to come highly recommended like 'Understanding Exposure',' The Photographer's Eye{Mind}', etc.

Can anybody point to a good, starting book for macro photography?

<sub>(Yes, I am asking for a printed book, not just a website.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Macro Photography by Ross Hoddinott.

This is the only book I've read on macro photography.  It covers the basics very thoroughly.  It seems to have lukewarm reviews on Amazon, mostly from people who wanted something more advanced.  If you want a real beginners book, I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Closeups in Nature by John Shaw.

A good easy read.  It doesn't get into digital photography, but the techniques and rules of thumb in it are useful.  It covers things like reversing lenses, how to light your subject, finding subjects (for example setting up bait to lure insects), and has some nice pictures, too.